# Android Lollipop ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE doesn't work as mentioned in Docs

Tags: android, android-camera, android-5.0-lollipop

My app started breaking on Lollipop which started me on a long quest of trying to figure out why and to fix it of course.

I finally decided that I should do it by the book as Google have written in the docs and here's the kicker, the code from their docs doesn't work!

I speak about code from here: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskCaptureIntent

```
<manifest ...>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                 android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
</manifest>
```

This piece of code which is advocated by google prevents the camera intent from starting it up itself on Lollipop!

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
```

This piece of code is supposed to help me specify the uri where I want the image to be, so that I can get the full sized image. This guy turns my data which I get back from the intent NULL. I talk about this data:`protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {`

I apologize for the rage but isn't it ridiculous that code that they write in the docs doesn't work? (If I'm doing something wrong please do tell me straight up)

This much I know. What I'd like to ask is if anyone knows how to get the full image after calling the **ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE** activity on Lollipop. The reason I need the full image and not just the thumbnail is that I need to use the EXIF data in the image for my app. (GPS data)
The EXIF gets added on its own if you open the camera app and take it, but if I call this activity, it doesn't directly save the image, I have to save it from the data that I get, and the most I'm getting out of it is a thumbnail using this code:

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
```

Comment: So the directory you're creating `photoFile` in is in the directory returned by [getExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)), but the camera doesn't seem to be able to write the file? Can you include the line where you create your `photoFile`?

Answer (score 0):

Why is there a max sdk inside an uses permission.

Please try again after you have changed

```
<manifest ...>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                 android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
</manifest>
```

To

```
<manifest ...>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I did that. It works obviously. What I'm ranting about is why its there in the docs.

Comment: That I don't know. Go tell Google. Why is this posted here? If you already knew the solution?

Comment: Sorry about the rudeness of my comment. I was really frustrated. The last part of my question is still unanswered. Which is : Why am I losing the EXIF data? Its not part of the image I'm saving.